# How to prevent pushing conflicts with a pre-receive hook placed on the remote bare repo?

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I have two branches on my bare repo, Master and "desarrollo" which is development in spanish. I want to create a pre-receive hook to avoid pushing conflicts to the central bare. This hook would be positioned on the central bare. This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

protected_branch='master'





# check each branch being pushed


while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha

do

if git diff "$old_sha" "$new_sha" | grep -qE '^+?(<<<<<|>>>>>)'; then
    echo "Saw a conflict marker in $(basename "$refname")."
    exit 1
fi

remote_branch=$(echo $remote_ref | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

if [ $protected_branch = $remote_branch ]

then

echo "ABORT PUSH: Not allowed to push directly to $protected_branch."

exit 1 # push will not execute

fi

done

exit 0
```

The first part is to prevent push of conflicted files, and the second part is to prevent pushing to master, I only allow pushes to desarrollo branch. The second part works perfectly, but the first part is not preventing the pushs, but it doesn't throw errors either when I try to upload a file with markups either. I want the transaction to fail altogether, not just reject the conflicted file but the whole push in case there is even a single file in conflict:

```
if git diff "$old_sha" "$new_sha" | grep -qE '^+?(<<<<<|>>>>>)'; then
        echo "Saw a conflict marker in $(basename "$refname")."
        exit 1
    fi
```

I must say I copied both parts from different sources, so there must be something wrong with the variable names, I just want to know is old_sha and new_sha variables are the reason of why this is failing since I'm not particularly good at making hooks

EDIT: I changed the string comparision from 5 to 7  '<<<<<<<' and now it works perfectly, the final script is

```
#!/bin/bash

protected_branch='master'


# check each branch being pushed


while read old_sha new_sha refname
do

if git diff "$old_sha" "$new_sha" | grep -qE '^+?(<<<<<<<|>>>>>>>)'; then
    echo "Saw a conflict marker in $(basename "$refname")."
    exit 1
fi

remote_branch=$(echo $refname | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

if [ $protected_branch = $remote_branch ]

then

echo "ABORT PUSH: Not allowed to push directly to $protected_branch."

exit 1 # push will not execute

fi

done

exit 0
```

Comment: You should backslash `+` sign at your regex. Without this merge conflicts still applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while seems to be wrong.
As you can see on `git help hooks` in the section about `pre-receive`, the input is `<old-value> SP <new-value> SP <ref-name> LF` per line, so your `while` should probably be `while read old_sha new_sha refname`. Then your original conflict check should be correct and you adapt the branch protection to use `$refname` instead of `$remote_ref`, then everything should probably work.

You probably copied this part from a `pre-push` script where the input is `<local ref> SP <local sha1> SP <remote ref> SP <remote sha1> LF` per line.

Comment: Now it works, but the problem is that it keeps rejecting the push no matter what with the message "Saw a conflict marker in desarrollo" and I don't seem to have files in conflict.....  git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U  I checked with that command and the list is empty.....Is the check I'm doing the right way to check for conflicts on the bash script using the <<<<<<< string or there is a better alternative out there??...My script is now https://codeshare.io/266oZ

Comment: I changed the if strings from '<<<<<' to '<<<<<<<' since I had files that had <<<<< and were not conflictive and git puts exactly 7 <  . Thank you very much for your help my friend. Problem Solved